# HP Pavillion Power 15" Windows 10 Freeze

Tags: windows-10, laptop, freeze, hp-pavilion

My Laptop keeps freezing once in a while. Once it freezes, it will stay frozen until i either unplug my charger or replug my charger.

I am still unable to fix it, but here are some input.

Laptop: HP Pavillion Power 15"

Some symptoms:

- Ram is around 80% usage or higher
- The computer does not lag
- This happens less frequently after restarting and happens more frequently the longer I kept the laptop on or without shutting down (sleeping and turning on)

Thing's I have tried to change:

- the max cpu power in the power management
- the power plan